# SSH ExitOnForwardFailure doesn't exit if port fails after successfully being established

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I've been using SSH to establish some remote port forwards.

```
ssh -NT -o ServerAliveInterval=20 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10  -R 22001:localhost:22 -R 59001:localhost:5900 user001@server_host
```

This seems to work well and I can access the ssh and vnc on the client machine via the opened server_hosts ports.

But I've found that occasionally that one of the port forwards can eventually fail after being established and this does not cause ExitOnForwardFailure to be exercised. eg A netstat on the server shows that 22001 is open, but 59001 is closed, and on the client the ssh command is still running happily.

Am I misunderstanding the operation of ExitOnForwardFailure for this usage? when I am expecting it to exit in this situation.

How can I ensure that SSH exits if either of the two port forwards in a command fails, and even if this failure didn't happen while establishing them?

Comment: By "failing" do you mean that `sshd` stops listening? or some actual (established) connection to `59001` gets terminated? At the moment I can't imagine the former, but the latter is normal and tells nothing about the condition of port forwarding itself. Auxiliary question: do you use `netstat -l` or just `netstat`? My point is `sshd` should listen on the port and it's not its job to monitor how many actual connections are being forwarded. Please [edit] the question and clarify. If `sshd` really stops listening, some log(s) may be useful.

Comment: sshd is still listening to port 22001 and forwarding data to that port. I have not monitored if an already established connection through 59001 gets terminated. I know that I can not establish new connections through 59001. I use `netstat -tulpn` and 59001 is not listed. I think this suggests that sshd is no longer listening to port 59001 and forwarding the data received at that port.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to look for more logging would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [you cannot forcefully free the port without killing the listening process](https://superuser.com/a/307629/432690), so if the port is no longer listened at, it's either because `sshd` died or it stopped listening by itself. In my tests the same `sshd` process listens on both ports. If it was killed, you would lose the entire SSH connection. It appears in your case it "chose" not to listen anymore.

Comment: If you are in charge of the server, run a separate `sshd -d` on another port, use it for port forwarding and monitor the output. Or increase the `LogLevel` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, reload the regular `sshd` service and monitor its logs (`sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=ssh.service`? – I'm not sure, please do your own research).

Answer (score 1):

Commenting in SSH source indicates that the `ExitOnForwardFailure` option is only intended to cause an exit if the `bind(2)` fails.

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9e34e0c59ab04514f9de9934a772283f7f372afe/readconf.h#L35

`int     exit_on_forward_failure;   /* Exit if bind(2) fails for -L/-R */`

According to the question, the initial binding of the ports succeeded. So the `ExitOnForwardFailure` will not cause an exit.

Unsure on how to produce the desired behavior requested in the question.